# Java reflection: getMethod(String method, Object[].class) not working

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following code:

```
public void myMethod(Object... args) {
    System.out.println("this is myMethod");
}

public void invokeMyMethod() {
    Method s = this.getClass().getMethod("myMethod", Object[].class);
    Object[] ex = new Object[2];
    ex[0] = "hi";
    ex[1] = "there";
    s.invoke(this, ex);
}
```

I'm getting the exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments. What's wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? In the call to `getMethod` or `invoke`?

Comment: It's clear that this isn't the *real* code, as there are typos (getClass -> getClass(), for example). Maybe the real code is different in some salient way?

Comment: Ernest, I've edited to add the brackets for user679573.  Other than that, the code was valid, so I felt this was a reasonable step.  (Mainly commenting so that others don't misunderstand your comment.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to call the method like this:

```
s.invoke(this, new Object[]{new Object[]{"hi", "there"}});
```

(... or use the alternative in @Jon's answer.)

The reason your current code fails is to do with the way that varadic methods are implemented in Java.  Essentially, `T1 xxx(T2... args)` is syntactic sugar for `T1 xxx(T2[] args)`.  And when you call the methods,  `xxx(arg1, arg2, arg3)` is syntactic sugar for `xxx(new T2[]{arg1, arg2, arg3})`.

In this case, you are trying to call a varadic method using another varadic method with the same array basetype, and there are multiple possible interpretations of the code.

When there are two possible interpretations of a varadic call, Java *assumes* that you are trying to use the "unsugared" version of the call instead of the "sugared" version.  Or to be more precise, the "sugared" interpretation is used *if and only if*:

- the number of actual arguments is not equal to the number of formal parameters, *or*
- the last actual argument is NOT assignment compatible with the (array) type of the last formal parameter.

If you are interested, this behaviour is specified in the JLS in section [15.12.4.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.4.2).

So ... my solution works by forcing the non-varadic interpretation and explicitly constructing the required array.  @Jon's solution works by forcing the *correct* varadic interpretation.

Comment: The sugared version is also used if there are less actual arguments - then it creates an empty array. This would apply for `s.invoke(this)`.

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is with the variable arguments (the `Object...`) that `Method.invoke` takes.

Changing this line

```
 s.invoke(this, ex);
```

to this

```
 s.invoke(this, (Object)ex);
```

will work.

In the background, `Object...` is passed as an `Object[]`.  Java's seeing your `Object[]` and choosing not to wrap it up in another `Object[]`.  By casting to `Object`, it now just sees that and reverts to its normal wrap-it-up behaviour - the same as what other answers are doing manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dp4j](http://dp4j.com) command-line to answer your question:

```
    $ javac -cp ../dp4j-1.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -All -Averbose=true MyClass.java
MyClass.java:7: Note: 
public class MyClass {

public MyClass() {
    super();
}

public void myMethod(Object... args) {
    System.out.println("this is myMethod");
}

@com.dp4j.Reflect()
public void invokeMyMethod() throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, java.lang.NoSuchFieldException, java.lang.IllegalAccessException, java.lang.NoSuchMethodException, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException {
    final java.lang.reflect.Method myMethodWithArrayMethod = Class.forName("MyClass").getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", .java.lang.Object[].class);
    myMethodWithArrayMethod.setAccessible(true);
    myMethodWithArrayMethod.invoke(this, new .java.lang.Object[1][]{new .java.lang.Object[2][]{"hi", "there"}});
}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    new MyClass().invokeMyMethod();
}
}
public void invokeMyMethod() {
            ^

$ java MyClass
this is myMethod
```