# Best idiom for creating a separate singleton for every type argument to a generic class?

Tags: java, generics, static, singleton, idioms

(Perhaps the complementary question to ["How to create a generic singleton class in java?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75175/1593077):)

```
class MyClass<T> {
    private static Map<Class<MyClass<?>>, MyClass<?>> s_instances =
        new HashMap<Class<MyClass<?>>, MyClass<?>>();

    public static MyClass<?> blah(Class<MyClass<?>> clz)
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (s_instances.get(clz) != null)
            return s_instances.get(clz);
        MyClass<?> instance = clz.newInstance();
        s_instances.put(clz, instance);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Is there a better idiom for having a singleton-per-type-argument-value?

**Edit**: Please do not answer merely to point out the lack of thread safety. Point taken. I'm asking whether I can do something more elegant than this map.

Comment: Not really sure what the point of having separate instances per type is, in your example. The new instance has to be of the exact type `MyClass` (not a subclass), so you can just call MyClass's constructor (no need for reflection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't do that. 
A. Your singleton is not thread safe. 
B. Be aware of [double check pattern issues at Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3580658/1593077). 
C. Is it really that hard to have static initializer in each class and have:

```
static {
   instance = new MySingleton();
}
```

and then

```
public static MySingleton getInstance() {
return instance
}
```

And if you really insist - 
 
1. You can probably define a singleton that will manage types in a map to an instance (key is class or full class name, value is object) 
2. You can add register your desired types there (I suggest they have private CTORs). 
3. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629706/java-accessing-private-constructor-with-type-parameters) answer in order to invoke the private CTOR , and create an instance to be placed in the value of the map entry. 
4. Provide a getInstance method to the repoistory mentioned at 1, with the signature of:

```
public Object getInstanceByType(Class<?> clazz)
```

This method will get the instance from the internal map.

Comment: Point taken about the thread-safety (although it is not an issue for my specific usage). Why would you recommend I not do this?

Comment: Because this means adding an infrastructure to the coder that almost does not posses any real value. You can have singleton per class with 6 lines of code per class - does this worth adding an infrastructure?

Comment: I don't follow... I don't know what the value of the type parameter is, so I can't add those 6 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is not thread safe:

```
private static Map<Class<MyClass<?>>, MyClass<?>> s_instances =
    new HashMap<Class<MyClass<?>>, MyClass<?>>();

public static MyClass<?> blah(Class<MyClass<?>> clz)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    if (s_instances.get(clz) != null)
        return s_instances.get(clz);
    // here1
    MyClass<?> instance = clz.newInstance();
    s_instances.put(clz, instance);
    // here2
    return instance;
}
```

Once one thread gets past the line marked `//here1`, a second thread may enter the method before the first thread is at the line marked `//here2`, hence creating a second "singleton" of the same kind and overwriting the first in the map.

The quick-fix would be to synchronize on the map:

```
public static MyClass<?> blah(Class<MyClass<?>> clz)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  synchronized(s_instances){
    if (s_instances.get(clz) != null)
        return s_instances.get(clz);
    // here1
    MyClass<?> instance = clz.newInstance();
    s_instances.put(clz, instance);
    // here2
    return instance;
  }
}
```

However, that would mean that many threads would have to wait a lot of the time, eventually perhaps killing your application. Probably what you should do is a two-step solution:

```
public static MyClass<?> blah(Class<MyClass<?>> clz)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
  Object candidate = s_instances.get(clz);
  if(clz.isInstance(candidate)){ // implicit null check
      return clz.cast(candidate);
  }
  synchronized(s_instances){
    Object candidate = s_instances.get(clz);
    if(clz.isInstance(candidate)){  // gotta check a second time in a
        return clz.cast(candidate); // synchronized context
    }
    MyClass<?> instance = clz.newInstance();
    s_instances.put(clz, instance);
    return instance;
  }
}
```

Also, a HashMap is not suited for concurrent access, so you should either wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedMap()`:

```
private static Map<Class<MyClass<?>>, MyClass<?>> s_instances =
    Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Class<MyClass<?>>, MyClass<?>>());
```

or go with a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Comment: This is why I suggested pre-registration of types in my answer. He can always try to reduce locking time by working with a predefined map of let's say N entries to internal maps. It's not exactly as ConcurrentMap, because he will manage the "segments" and will create all of them when application starts, so you won't need to lock on adding new segment.