# Trying to instantiate Math class

Tags: java

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong right here?

```
private static java.lang.Math a = new java.lang.Math();
```

It's resulting an error, but I have no idea why.

Comment: `Math` is static, you can't `new` it.

Comment: Think about what it is you intend to do with your `a` object, and that might help you realise why it's an error.

Comment: My question is why do you need to do `new java.lang.Math` ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: a.abs(int min - int max);

Comment: Though Math is a static, using it like a java.lang.Math is redundant.. java.lang.* imports by default.

Comment: I already have a Math class so thats why I am trying other options.

Comment: @user2192658 edit your question and put that in there.

Answer (score 9):

You can't instantiate a Math instance.  It's all static methods.  There's no public default constructor.

Comment: There's no default _public_ constructor, but there is a _private_ one

Comment: And that's deliberate, to keep people from instantiating it.

Comment: The odd thing is that `Math` really should not be a singleton class of static methods, since there are two classes with the same methods: `Math` and `StrictMath`. I can imagine more versions of the interface of `Math` that trade accuracy for speed. Look at the Quake 3 Inverse Square Root routine for reasons why you'd do this.

Comment: That's history; can't do anything about that.  You'll see that the original Math was part of JDK 1.0, but StrictMath was not.

Comment: Yes, I get it about the private constructor.

Answer (score 3):

*Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong right here?*

The answer is you are trying to instantiate a class with a single `private` constructor, from outside the class.

```
/**
 * Don't let anyone instantiate this class.
 */
private Math() {}
```

*a.abs(int min - int max); !!*

You can do the following way :

```
int min = xxx;
int max = yyy;
int abs = Math.abs(min-max);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to instantiate java.lang.Math... and I'm not sure why.

Just use it like this:

```
java.lang.Math.sin(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why to create new Object,Its final class and all methods are static.

I was trying to say why to create an object if all methods are static and since it's final ,constructor call may fail

Comment: Are you asking a question, commenting or trying to provide an answer?

Comment: trying to provide an answer

Comment: What is the relation between a `final` class and `static` methods?

Comment: there is no relation..As i was trying to say  why to create an object if all methods are static and since it's final ,constructor call may fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ([without reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629706/java-accessing-private-constructor-with-type-parameters)) create object of class if you don't have access to its constructor, like in this case, where constructor is private.

> I already have a Math class so thats why I am trying other options

All important methods of `java.lang.Math` are static so you don't need instance of that class to invoke them. Just use `Math.abs(x - y)` or in your case `java.lang.Math.abs(x - y)` to specify that you want to use `java.lang.Math`, not your class.

---

In case you just want to use just few methods from `java.lang.Math` you can just import them like

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
```

and use it like

```
abs(10 - 20)
```

---

You can also try this way

```
java.lang.Math a = null;
a.abs(x - y);   // compilator will change it to 
                //java.lang.Math.abs(x - y) since abs is static method
```

but I would stay with `java.lang.Math.abs(x - y)` since it is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create an object of Math class because the constructor of Math class has a private modifier.

Further, all the methods in the class are static. So you can use them directly ( ex : Math.method() ). By extension, the presence of only static methods in the class does not ever necessitate object construction.

So, one cannot instantiate Math because *it was designed such that no one should ever find a need to instantiate it*.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate Math, but you shouldn't, unless it is for some obscure reason.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Constructor<?> constructor = Math.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    Math math = (Math) constructor.newInstance();
    ...
}
```