# Reflecting a class with only package level access

Tags: java, reflection

I'm not quite sure how to go about reflecting a class that only has package-level access.  I know how to reflect any class that has public access, but I cannot figure out how to reflect the following example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test t = new test();
        Constructor<one.oneimpl> con = one.oneimpl.class.getDeclaredConstructor(test.class);
        oneimpl o = con.newInstance(t);
        o.doIt();
    }
}
```

======================

```
package one;
// implementation class for mimicking android api
class oneimpl extends one {
    Test mTest;
    private oneimpl(test t){mTest = t;}
    public void doIt(){System.out.println("Do It!");}
    public void dontDoit(){System.out.println("Don't Do It!");}
}
```

======================

```
package one;
// abstract class for mimicking android api
abstract class one {
    public void doIt();
    public void dontDoIt();
}
```

======================

```
package one;
// empty class for mimicking android api
public class test {}
```

As you can see, the class `one` only has package-level access.  This makes reflecting the class difficult for me.  I continue to get compiler errors that states:

```
Main.java:4: error: oneimpl is not public in one; cannot be accessed from outside package
oneimpl o = con.newInstance(t);
```

I've reviewed a few posts, to solve this on my own, but even after reading most of the "similar questions", reading the `AccessibilityObject` api, and reading generic reflection procedures it's still unclear to me how to achieve this.

Ultimately what I am trying to do is to reflect particular portions of the API to build objects so that soot/spark can build a proper call graph.  I'm not actually working inside the android API.

Comment: you need to call "setAccessible". see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629706/java-accessing-private-constructor-with-type-parameters

Comment: This particular example is quite a bit different than the link you provided.  It is assumed that the classes given in the example are in the same package and the constructor is private.  I have a public constructor with a package-level access class.  My code won't even compile.  See the above error generated.

Comment: Actually you have a private constructor, look closely at your declaration in `oneimpl`: `private oneimpl(test t){mTest = t;}`. And even if it was public you'd still have to call `setAccessible` since public constructors/methods in inaccessible classes are considered inaccessible.

Comment: Ha! that I do.  That is a slight deviation from the android API that I am working on. In the end, the visibility of the constructor is a moot point.  But thank you for bringing that to my attention!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use reflection at every step in order to do what you're trying to do.

First, since you can't directly reference a package-scoped class in package `one` from outside that package you'll need to load that class dynamically (also note the use of `?` instead of directly using `oneimpl`):

```
Class<?> oneImplClass = Class.forName("one.oneimpl");
```

Then you can get the constructor and the `doIt` method (make sure you set both of these as accessible, otherwise you'll get runtime errors):

```
Constructor<?> constructor = oneImplClass.getDeclaredConstructor(test.class);
constructor.setAccessible(true);
Method doIt = oneImplClass.getDeclaredMethod("doIt");
doIt.setAccessible (true);
```

Next, instantiate the class. You'll have to cast it to `Object` since you can't reference the class directly):

```
Object oneImpl = (Object) constructor.newInstance();
```

Lastly you can invoke the `doIt` method:

```
doIt.invoke(oneImpl);
```

As one last note: you should follow Java naming conventions when naming your classes: `oneimpl` should be `OneImpl` and `test` should be `Test`. Otherwise things like `one.oneimpl` end up looking like a package name rather than a fully qualified class name.

Comment: So I knew how to do it, I just didn't put all the pieces together :(.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    test t = new test();
    Class<?> oneimpl = Main.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("one.oneimpl");
    Constructor<?> con = oneimpl.getDeclaredConstructor(test.class);
    con.setAccessible(true);
    Object o = con.newInstance(t);
    Method m = oneimpl.getDeclaredMethod("doIt");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(o);
}
```