# I want to test a failure case which is triggered by a library's non-public exception. How do I throw this exception?

Tags: java, exception, testing, reflection, mockito

The [Tinkerforge](http://www.tinkerforge.com/) library throws `TimeoutException` and `NotConnectedException` (among others). I'd like to throw these in my test case, so I can test that my error-handling code works correctly.

When I try

```
when(brickletLEDStripMock.getRGBValues(any(), any())).thenThrow(new NotConnectedException("Test"));
```

IntelliJ tells me that the exception is not public and cannot be accessed from outside the package.

Is there a way to throw it anyway, maybe with Powermock?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [Fran Montero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4763733/fran-montero) I now got this working code:

```
Constructor<NotConnectedException> constructor;
constructor = NotConnectedException.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
constructor.setAccessible(true);
NotConnectedException exception = constructor.newInstance();

when(brickletLEDStripMock.getRGBValues(anyInt(), anyShort())).thenThrow(exception);
```

Comment: Maybe you can access the protected class using reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629706/java-accessing-private-constructor-with-type-parameters

Comment: That works, thank you! If you want to formulate this as an answer, I'll upvote it :)

Comment: done! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access that class using reflection api:

```
Constructor<Foo> constructor;
 constructor = Foo.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Object.class);
 constructor.setAccessible(true);
 Foo<String> foo = constructor.newInstance("arg1");
```

Check [Java: accessing private constructor with type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629706/java-accessing-private-constructor-with-type-parameters)