# How to instantiate generic class which has a private constructor with an argument

Tags: java, reflection

I'm creating a java application with 3rd-party library, and want to instantiate its class. However, the class is generic and only has a private constructor.

I've tried to create an instance by Guice injection.
`Test<T>` can't be modified, so I did neither annotate with @Inject nor add a zero-argument constructor that is not private.

```java
public class Test<T> {
    private final T value;

    private Test(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.value.toString();
    }
}
```

```java
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new TypeLiteral<Test<String>>() {
        });
    }
});
Test<String> test = (Test<String>) injector.getInstance(Test.class);
System.out.println(String.format("%s", test));
```

```
1) Could not find a suitable constructor in com.example.app.Test. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
```

I want to know how can I put an argument to the constructor of Test class, and how to instantiate it.

Comment: if the constructor is declared private, you can only instantiate it from within the same class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: accessing private constructor with type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629706/java-accessing-private-constructor-with-type-parameters)

Comment: If the constructor is private, there should be a good reason for the implementer of the 3rd party library to write it that way. So the best way is to refer to the documentation of that library and see how you can use it the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (but probably you should not) do this using reflections:

```
    Constructor<Test> declaredConstructor = Test.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Object.class);
    declaredConstructor.setAccessible(true); // or if (declaredConstructor.trySetAccessible()) on java 9+
    Test<String> obj = declaredConstructor.newInstance("value of first parameter");
```

Generics are ignored in runtime so you just need to use lower bound here `Object.class`. If it would be `class Test<T extends Something>` then you would look for `Something.class` but otherwise it is Object by default.

If that test class is from some library maybe there is method that creates it... so you could avoid using reflections.