# mock private constructor and its multiple parameters with mockk

Tags: java, kotlin, unit-testing, junit, mockk

I want to mock the private constructor of a class with its multiple parameters (with Kotlin):

```
public final class Foo {

   public static class Bla {
        public final CustomType1 property1;
        public final CustomType2 property2;

        private Bla(CustomType1 param1, CustomType2 param2) {
            this.property1 = (CustomType1)Objects.requireNonNull(param1);
            this.property2 = (CustomType2)Objects.requireNonNull(param2);
        }
    }
}
```

Through that I try to mock the properties (`property1, property2`) which are otherwise nearly impossible to mock.

Comment: "which are otherwise nearly impossible to mock" you should consider redesigning your class to allow for testability.

Comment: Is `Foo.Bla` your own class, or is it part of a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was possible to mock the parameter `property1` while wrapping it with an extending function:

```
internal fun Foo.Bla.getProperty1(): CustomType1 {
   return property1
}
```

I've accessed the value of `property1` then in the implementation though `getProperty1()`.
With that workaround it could be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a private constructor is not what you are looking for. With a private constructor you restrict the object creation to only within the class `Bla`. Take a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-private-constructors).

If for some reason you are required to have the constructor private, then you could try using reflections as mentioned in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629706/java-accessing-private-constructor-with-type-parameters), but keep in mind that it will essentially set the `private` modifier to `public` at runtime.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get how reflection could help him with mocking the private constructor, could you elaborate? Because I'm in a similar [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78068110/how-to-port-a-python-monkeypatch-in-kotlin)

Comment: In Java you can use the `Method#setAccessible` method to make it public at runtime and invoke it. I don't know how this is done in other languages or if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are only 2 ways. The first one is already mentioned @micartey and the second one is to use `PowerMockito`. It's a strong tool that allow you to mock static and private methods. If we are talking about code. so it should look like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
class FooTest {

    @Test
    fun testBlaConstructor() {

        val customType1Mock = mock(CustomType1::class.java)
        val customType2Mock = mock(CustomType2::class.java)

        val blaMock = mock(Bla::class.java)
        whenNew(Bla::class.java)
            .withArguments(customType1Mock, customType2Mock)
            .thenReturn(blaMock)

        val blaInstance = Bla(customType1Mock, customType2Mock)
        verify(blaMock).property1 = customType1Mock
        verify(blaMock).property2 = customType2Mock
    }
```

Dont forget to prepare dependency for PowerMockito

**NOTE: Power Mock should be used in legacy applications where you cannot change the code which has been given to you. Often such code does not have unit/integration tests and even small change can result in bugs in application.**