# How to port a python monkeypatch in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockk

Let me start by giving you some background, LakeFS has:

- two automatically generated clients, one for [Python](https://github.com/treeverse/lakeFS/tree/master/clients/python) and one for [Java](https://github.com/treeverse/lakeFS/tree/master/clients/java)
- an high-level [wrapper](https://github.com/treeverse/lakeFS/tree/master/clients/python-wrapper), unfortunately Python-only

I rewrote the latter for Kotlin [here](https://github.com/elect86/ktor-sample/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/lakefs), now I'm writing/porting some tests, in particular [this one](https://github.com/treeverse/lakeFS/blob/master/clients/python-wrapper/tests/utests/test_branch.py#L32)

```py
def test_branch_create(monkeypatch):
    branch = get_test_branch()
    source = "main"
    with monkeypatch.context():
        def monkey_create_branch(_self, repo_name, branch_creation, *_):
            assert repo_name == branch.repo_id
            assert branch_creation.name == branch.id
            assert branch_creation.source == source
            return lakefs_sdk.BranchCreation(name=branch.id, source=source)

        monkeypatch.setattr(lakefs_sdk.BranchesApi, "create_branch", monkey_create_branch)
        branch.create(source)
```

where they mock the original `BranchesApi.create_branch` [here](https://github.com/treeverse/lakeFS/blob/master/clients/python/lakefs_sdk/api/branches_api.py#L223)

On JVM, `branch.create(source)` calls [this](https://github.com/elect86/ktor-sample/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/lakefs/branch.kt#L144):

```
fun create(sourceReference: ReferenceType, existOk: Boolean = false): Branch {
    val referenceId = getId(sourceReference)
    val branchCreation = BranchCreation().name(id).source(referenceId)
    try {
        client.branchesApi.createBranch(repoId, branchCreation).execute()
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        if (!existOk)
            throw e
    }
    return this
}
```

where `client: ApiClient` is a property of the (last) super class and `branchesApi` is nothing more than a simple getter

```
val ApiClient.branchesApi: BranchesApi
    get() = BranchesApi(this)
```

`BranchesApi::createBranch` comes from the generated Java client [here](https://github.com/treeverse/lakeFS/blob/master/clients/java/src/main/java/io/lakefs/clients/sdk/BranchesApi.java#L482):

```
public APIcreateBranchRequest createBranch(String repository, BranchCreation branchCreation) {
    return new APIcreateBranchRequest(repository, branchCreation);
}
```

and then `APIcreateBranchRequest::execute` [here](https://github.com/treeverse/lakeFS/blob/master/clients/java/src/main/java/io/lakefs/clients/sdk/BranchesApi.java#L414) will execute the REST API request:

```
public String execute() throws ApiException {
    ApiResponse<String> localVarResp = createBranchWithHttpInfo(repository, branchCreation);
    return localVarResp.getData();
}
```

So the part to mock to disable the real REST Api call, in my case on the JVM, has to be this last `APIcreateBranchRequest::execute` and not `BranchesApi::createBranch` like on Python

So far, my test file looks like this:

```
    val testRepo = Repo("test_repo", testClient)
    val testBranch = testRepo branch "test_branch"

    @Test
    fun testBranchCreate() {

        val branch = testBranch
        val source = "main"
        mockkConstructor(APIcreateBranchRequest::class)
        every {
            anyConstructed<APIcreateBranchRequest>().execute()
        } answers { "" }

        branch.create(source)
    }
```

In order to call those `assert`s, I need to find a way to either capture:

- the `APIcreateBranchRequest` class instance
- the `APIcreateBranchRequest` (private) constructor arguments

But after many hours and attempts, I couldn't figure out a way